# How to remove files under inspection state in collaborator

Tags: code-collaborator

I have unknowingly uploaded few unwanted files in one of my collaborator review. The review is currently under inspection and there are comments on this unwanted files. my architect has asked  to remove this unwanted files.
Can some one suggest  how to remove files from collaborator at inspection phase?

Answer (score 0):

Possibility to delete depends how were the files uploaded.

1. Were the files part of a change batch with other files?
2. Were the files in a change by itself?
3. Or were the files uploaded as files themselves?
   (There is option to add files to a review that are not part of a change.)

Option 1) ... files can't be removed.
Options 2), 3) ... removal may be possible depending on permission setup, it may need administrator intervention.